# Sum values in one dataframe based on values of column in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sum

I have two dataframes that look like the following

```
library(dplyr)

State = c('AK','AL','AR','AZ')
Perc = c(0.0023, 0.0034, 0.0043, 0.065)

df1 <- data.frame(State, Perc)

ID = c('A','B','C','D','E')
States = c('AK','AK; AL', 'AK; AL; AR; AZ', 'AR; AZ', 'AL')

df2 <- data.frame(ID, States)
```

I want to create a new column in df2 that locates the value of Perc in df1 for a particular state and sums up the values for each ID.  Ideally, I would like to have a new df2 that looks like this:

```
ID    States           SumPerc
A     AK               0.0023
B     AK; AL           0.0057
C     AK; AL; AR; AZ   0.0750
D     AR; AZ           0.0693
E     AL               0.0034
```

How should I go about this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we split `df2` into a row for each state, then we join in the `Perc` data. Then we just need to aggregate back up based on the `ID` group, and we re-concatenate `States` and sum up `Perc`

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% separate_rows(States, sep = "; ") %>% 
  left_join(., df1, by = c("States" = "State")) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarize(
    Perc = sum(as.numeric(Perc), na.rm = TRUE), 
    States = paste(States, collapse= "; ")
  )


  ID      Perc States        
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>         
1 A     0.0023 AK            
2 B     0.0057 AK; AL        
3 C     0.075  AK; AL; AR; AZ
4 D     0.0693 AR; AZ        
5 E     0.0034 AL
```